# setTimeout with zero delay used often in web pages, why?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

I noticed a trend in web pages, that they use setTimeout(*function(){...}*, **0**) more often instead of just making the call.

I wonder why, couldn't find something about it. Except for the reason that it's used as trick to avoid a stack overflow. But this is not always the case for the places it's being used.