# ngRepeat and directives execution order

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

When an Angular directive contains an ngRepeat element, the ngRepeat execution appears to to occur after the containing directive's link execution.

Is there a mechanism ($watch, $observe, etc) that I can use to wire up a response after the ngRepeat execution?

Here's an example of the behavior:
http://plnkr.co/edit/yBiSvveeSissU7Rik6Kp?p=preview

I want to operate in a state in the directive where the inputs are available.

My primary goal is to alter the elements of ngRepeat from the containing directive.

Answer (score 5):

The typical way to determine when ng-repeat has finished is to write a directive that checks to see if `$last` is true.  Then you can call a function (defined on a parent/ancestor scope) or emit an event, inside a `$timeout` callback or `$evalAsync`.

For more details and examples, see [Calling a function when ng-repeat has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished)