# How to trigger event after all children scopes got rendered?

Tags: javascript, events, angularjs

I've created a plunker to demonstrate my question, it is in here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/lPyCJL .

In the plunker, when you click the button it will change the model, adding new children elements. I need to perform some element styling once entire HTML is in the DOM.

Where should I hook in?
Greg

Comment: Not sure what you're asking exactly? What type of styling? You could hide everything until it loads using ng-cloak.

Comment: In your real app, what would add new children elements? Is it a button like in your sample or is it some other external event?

Comment: In angular DOM rendering does not provide a way to determine when the rendering is complete. Your best bet would be to use $timeout service and delay the styling by a arbitrary amount of time.

Comment: See if this one helps: [Calling a function when ng-repeat has finished](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished)