# AngularJs running code after ng-repeat binding happens

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a data table that I am loading with a call to a $resource.  It is doing a query and using the returned value in an ng-repeat within the view.  This all works great.  The problem is that I am trying to use the DataTables jquery plugin and need that to be run after the table is loaded with all the rows, meaning after angular has run the ng-repeat with the updated values that came back from the $resource call.

Here is what my controller code looks like at the moment:

```
  $scope.model = {
      roles: []
  };

  $scope.model.roles = $resource('/api/admin/user/role').query();

  $scope.$watch('model.roles', function () {
      console.log('watch called');
      handleDataTables();
  });

  var handleDataTables = function() {
      $('#rolelist').dataTable({
          "sPaginationType": "bs_full"
      });
  };
```

I thought that the watch would get called when the rows of the table were already created, but it doesn't appear to be working that way.  I also tried calling handleDataTables in the success callback of the $resource.query call but that doesn't work either.

I can get it working by doing a timeout before calling handleDataTables, but that just feels dirty.

Comment: I'd advise against using a $watch in your controller if possible. Sometimes it's unavoidable, but you'll run into fewer issues (and you'll see better performance) if you try to handle calling `handleDataTables()` during the actual events that change the collection in the repeater.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a function when ng-repeat has finished](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished)

Comment: I was able to use the onFinishRender directive that is described in the link on the duplicate question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had same problem with jQuery dataTable and ng-repeat of Angular. And finally solved the problem with this code. You can try that and I hope help you to solve your problem. 
HTML:

```
<div ng-app="tableExample">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <button ng-click="addData()">Add Data</button>
         <h2>This table uses columns defined in controller</h2> 
        <table my-table options="options"></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
var dialogApp = angular.module('tableExample', []);

dialogApp.directive('myTable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E, A, C',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            var dataTable = element.dataTable(scope.options);

            scope.$watch('options.aaData', handleModelUpdates, true);

            function handleModelUpdates(newData) {
                var data = newData || null;
                if (data) {
                    dataTable.fnClearTable();
                    dataTable.fnAddData(data);
                }
            }
        },
        scope: {
            options: "="
        }
    };
});

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.options = {
        aoColumns: [{
            "sTitle": "Surname"
        }, {
            "sTitle": "First Name"
        }],
        aoColumnDefs: [{
            "bSortable": false,
            "aTargets": [0, 1]
        }],
        bJQueryUI: true,
        bDestroy: true,
        aaData: [
            ["Webber", "Adam"]
        ]
    };

    $scope.addData = function () {
        $scope.counter = $scope.counter + 1;
        $scope.options.aaData.push([$scope.counter, $scope.counter * 2]);
    };

    $scope.counter = 0;
}
```

I tested the above example, it works awesome.