# Turning jQuery plugin into directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, bxslider

I'm trying to turn an existing jquery plugin into a directive to use in my angular app.

My html:

```
<div ng-controller="BoxController">
  <ul class="bxslider" bx-slider="{mode: 'horizontal', pager: false, controls: true, minSlides: 1, maxSlides:4, slideWidth: 350, slideMargin:10, infiniteLoop: false, hideControlOnEnd: true}">
    <li ng-repeat="obj in items track by $index">
      <div class="item"><img ng-src="{{obj + $index}}" /></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So my directive is `bx-slider` or `bxSlider`

```
app.directive('bxSlider', function()
    {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs)
            {
                angular.element(element).bxSlider(scope.$eval(attrs.bxSlider));
            }
        }
    });
```

What happens is I get a list of images in a bulleted list. The CSS is certainly getting applied however the actions of it being a carousel isn't working. It is supposed to be something like this:

http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-dynamic-number-slides

However I get

http://dopserv1.dop.com/bxslider/

with no errors in the console or anything. If I do a `console.log` on `attrs.bxSlider` I see all the params I defined in the HTML above. What am I doing wrong here? I am including jQuery 1.10.2 above the angular include.

Comment: try wrapping in `$timeout`... need to give `ng-repeat` a chance to complete digest

Comment: wrap what part in `$timeout`?

Comment: initialization of slider plugin

Comment: Ah, well that did work. I'm curious, is there a more "right" way of doing this rather than using a timeout?

Comment: `ng-repeat` creates scope for each item, part of scope is `$last`....could trigger the slider from that when it is true

Comment: scope in the directive contains `$last`? I'm getting undefined from `scope.$last`. Sorry for my ignorance lol

Comment: would require another directive on the slides....see this crude demo  http://plnkr.co/edit/fLwrFFZTXt9mjiDPGgMO?p=preview

Comment: I see now, thank you for the example. I think I will stick with a timeout.

Comment: Also `element.bxSlider(scope.$eval(attrs.bxSlider))` is all you need on that line. `element` in your directive is the same as `$(this)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/KCwzmG?p=preview

With the part of the solution coming from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished).

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-ng-controller="BoxController">
    <ul class="bxslider" data-bx-slider="mode: 'horizontal', pager: false, controls: true, minSlides: 1, maxSlides:4, slideWidth: 350, slideMargin:10, infiniteLoop: false, hideControlOnEnd: true">
      <li data-ng-repeat="obj in items track by $index" data-notify-when-repeat-finished>
        <div class="item">
          <img data-ng-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/{{$index + 1}}/" />
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('BoxController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
}]);

app.directive('bxSlider', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('repeatFinished', function () {
                console.log("ngRepeat has finished");
                element.bxSlider(scope.$eval('{' + attrs.bxSlider + '}'));
            });
        }
    }
}])
.directive('notifyWhenRepeatFinished', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit('repeatFinished');
                });
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```