# AngularJS filtered List not calling directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If you ng-repeat over a filtered collection, directives are fired only on startup and collection expansion. If you reduce the collection, nothing happens.

Try

```
aa  -> nothing happens
then 
backspace  -> directive called
```

in my [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ISjcWYoWWYCbTBgLlW9B?p=preview)

Here is my HTML-Fragment

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
       <input type="text" ng-model="q">
       <div ng-repeat="item in arr | filter:q" test>
            {{item}}<br>       
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my Angular-Code

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.arr = ['a','aa','aaa','ab','bb'];
  })
  .directive('test', function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, element, attr) { 
        if (scope.$first) 
          alert("Directive called");
      }
    };
  });
```

Is this the desired behaviour?
Is this a caching issue?

How can I force ng-repeat to rerender on every change of collection?

Update:

Michael's [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VEnoHc4qPiyy8OM3T0RD?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is desired behavior. Your `link` function is only called if the elements are created by `ngRepeat`. So `$first` ist true in your link function if the list is populated for the first time. If you reduce the list by your filter the remaining elements are not recreated and your link function is not called. if you hit the back button a new element is created and now the link function for that element is called.

I am not quite sure what you try to achieve, but i guess you would like to know in your directive wether the element is the first element in the list. To achieve this i would set `$first` as a value of the directive `test`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in arr | filter:q" test="{{$first}}" 
          ng-class="{ active: $first || $last }">
        {{item}}<br>
</div>
```

in your directive you can observe this value:

```
link: function(scope, element, attr) { 
    attr.$observe('test', function(newValue){
      if(newValue=='true'){
        console.log("Directive called..", newValue, scope.item);
      }
    });
  }
```

the console prints out every time the element becomes the first in the list.

Comment: Nice hack, but is there no chance to force ng-repeat to rerender completely? $first element is not important. Need a [ng-repeat-ready-Directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished)