# Jquery bxslider not working + Angular js ng-repeat issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, bxslider

I'm working on a Angular js project where I get number of terms and i'm using **ng repeat** to show each term in the front end .**it works fine**.I have shown them in a  [bx slider (jquery responsive bxslider)](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified)
[image]

Following will be the main code.

**Javascript code**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.slider4').bxSlider({
        slideWidth: 300,
        minSlides: 2,
        maxSlides: 3,
        moveSlides: 1,
        slideMargin: 10
      });
    });
     </script>
```

**HTML code**

```
<div class="slider4">
    <div ng-repeat="term in terms" >  {{term.name}}</div>   
  </div>
```

I can see all the terms are **loaded nicely** but **when I click arrow keys slider doesn't work**
.I can't figure out the issue.I'm pretty sure the problem is with **ng-repeat**. Because when i remove ng-repeat and just add some images/divs to the `<div class="slider4"></div>`it works fine.

Can some one help me? Why is this not working? **Is it a draw back in Angular js**?Can't I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

bxSlider doesn't work because the jQuery executes before your ng-repeat has finished.

You can use something like finishingmoves' directive to execute a function after ng-repeat has finished.

The directive is the following:

```
var module = angular.module('testApp', [])
.directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        if (scope.$last === true) {
            $timeout(function () {
                scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
            });
        }
    }
    }
});
```

(finishingmoves directive from here: [Calling a function when ng-repeat has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished))

You can see an example of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/paulocoelho/BsMqq/4/

Hope that helps and don't forget to vote!

Answer (score 1):

You can call method when window load like this use

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {  
 });
```

in the place of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not my solution, but I'd thought I would pass it along.

**I like this solution the best (Utilizes directive controllers)**

```
// slightly modified from jsfiddle

// bxSlider directive
controller: function() {},
link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
    controller.initialize = function() {
        element.bxSlider(BX_SLIDER_OPTIONS);
    };
}

// bxSliderItem directive
require: '^bxSlider',
link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
    if (scope.$last) {
        controller.initialize();
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CaioToOn/Q5AcH/8/

Answer (score 0):

In ng-repeat call any function(ex:initBxslider()) on $last object

```
<div ng-repeat="term in terms" >  
  {{term.name}}
  <span ng-init="$last && data.initBxslider()"></span>
</div>
```

in controller:

```
 $scope.initBxslider = function () {
        $timeout(function () {
            $('.slider4').bxSlider({
               slideWidth: 300,
               minSlides: 2,
               maxSlides: 3,
               moveSlides: 1,
               slideMargin: 10
             });
        });
    }
```