# Run function after AngularJS binding takes place

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple app that uses Angular to run a HTTP GET request and then sets the returned data to an array that is bound to the DOM using `ng-repeat` and I want to run some code that manipulates this DOM after it is done being placed into the `body`. What is the best way to make this work?

```
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'https://www.*******.com/WebApi/Alert/Items/all',
                cache: false
            })
            .success(function (data, status) {
                $scope.alerts = data.result.Alerts;
                jQuery('.aWidget').iconalt(); // THIS IS THE CODE I WANT TO RUN
            })
            .error(function (data, status) {
                console.log(data);
                alert("error");
            });
```

See, I want to run the line `jQuery('.aWidget').iconalt()` after all the DOM is placed into the document. Right now, this line is executing too fast and so it "thinks" that there are no `.aWidget` elements in the DOM

Is there some kind of callback that I can inject into AngularJS that gets called after the DOM is loaded?

Comment: It is difficult to know when rendering in AngularJS is complete. The easiest and not so perfect way is to use $timeout with a decent lag. Or lopk at this SO post that tasks about how to know ng-repeat completed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished

Comment: I'd put the jQuery invocation into a simple directive and add it to your `ng-repeat` elements. It's a clean way forward without having to wrestle with Angular's digest and DOM-rendering pipeline by using constructs like `$timeout` or `$evalAsync`.

Answer (score 1):

You're running up against the digest cycle, which doesn't finish until your code returns. So what you REALLY need is to return but then run a piece of code AFTER that. There's a common JavaScript trick that does this:

```
// I used Angular's $timeout, but you can use setTimeout() just as easily...
$timeout(function() {
    jQuery('.aWidget').iconalt();
}, 50);
```

There is also a very cool module called [setImmediate.js](https://github.com/YuzuJS/setImmediate) that polyfills the "setImmediate" function coming in modern browsers. This trick is used so often that browser makers realized it was something they should provide a fast, "correct" way to perform. Your code probably doesn't need to be run faster than 50ms later - the user will never notice... But if you were doing something that DID you could use this tool to run a task on the "next tick", so using the trick wouldn't be a performance hit.