# How to modify code that will be transcluded or access it after ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have code like this:

```
<my-dropdown>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items"><a>{{item.text}}</a></li>
</my-dropdown>
```

and I need to hide all li except one (I have ng-transclude in 2 places) but I can't access the source html, I can't modify the code before angular will read it and I can't access DOM after ng-repeat.

Comment: Why are you asking the same thing twice?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24513237/directive-that-run-after-ng-repeat

Comment: @JoseM the question was different but the code was the same. I've changed title and it appear as the same. I'll change title to be exactly what have in text.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it:

```
<my-dropdown>
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-hide="$index!=2"><a>{{item.text}}</a></li>
</my-dropdown>
```

Will hide all but the third li

Comment: I need to do this in directive I have logic inside.

Comment: Also I have 2 ng-transclude so I can use this.

Comment: Also Also this is not how you create reusable compontents.