# Jarvis.widget doesn't get rendered in AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, singlepage

I have a hard time figuring out what to do in my AngularJs single-page . I use `ng-repeat` to display a number of widgets. The plugin is "**Jarvis widget v2.0**". My problem is, that the article container does not have the functionality from the Jarvis widget (fullscreen, collapse etc.).

The data is delayed because of a HTTP GET call. If I hard-code the dataSeries it works 100%, but it seems that the Jarvis widgets gets rendered before the **success** of the HTTP GET. I have tried to find a solution for days and my guess is that a directive is the solution, but I'm lost!

```
<article class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6" ng-repeat="chart in dataSeries">
       <div class="jarviswidget" id="wid-id-02" data-widget-editbutton="false" data-widget-colorbutton="false" data-widget-deletebutton="false"></div>
</article>
```

This is my first post, so if I forgot something i apologize in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, with help from Darneas I came up with a solution.

1. I implemented this: 
   : [Calling a function when ng-repeat has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished)
2. I made sure that "widget-grid" wasn't initialized (I had some test widgets)
3. I called "setup_widgets_desktop()" from the ngRepeatFinished

This was succesfull. Thank you Darneas. I wouldn't had found a solution otherwise.

I couldn't get the widget directive to work, which looks like a great solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

The code inside `function setup_widgets_desktop()` is going to create the widgets based on the current(!) HTML content. As `ng-repeat` will render your element after you have a success from your HTTP request, there are no elements present when the function is called.

In order to achieve the behaviour you want, execute `setup_widgets_desktop()` again after your callback returns. You might need to make sure it is delayed by using `$timeout(setup_widgets_desktop, 1000)`. I am using it this way, but not sure if it is a general requirement to have a delay.

The best option would be to extract the call `$('#widget-grid').jarvisWidgets()` into an directive. You could replace `$('#widget-grid')` with getting the current $(element), so it is only bound to the current element and not some fixed ID inside the DOM. If you need more advice on this, just drop me a line.

**Edit (sample code):**

In my project I am using the following Angular service (you have to replace yourApp, the HTTP URI and the jQuery selector to your needs):

```
(function(yourApp) {
    "use strict";
    yourApp.factory("presenter", function ($timeout) {
        var layout = function () {
            $("#widgets-grid").jarvisWidgets({
                grid: "article",
                widgets: '.jarviswidget',
                localStorage: false,
//                deleteSettingsKey: '#deletesettingskey-options',
//                settingsKeyLabel: 'Reset settings?',
//                deletePositionKey: '#deletepositionkey-options',
//                positionKeyLabel: 'Reset position?',
                sortable: false,
                buttonsHidden: false,
                // toggle button
                toggleButton: false,
                toggleClass: 'fa fa-minus | fa fa-plus',
                toggleSpeed: 200,
                onToggle: function () {
                },
                // delete btn
                deleteButton: false,
                deleteClass: 'fa fa-times',
                deleteSpeed: 200,
                onDelete: function () {
                },
                // edit btn
                editButton: false,
                editPlaceholder: '.jarviswidget-editbox',
                editClass: 'fa fa-cog | fa fa-save',
                editSpeed: 200,
                onEdit: function () {
                },
                colorButton: false,
                // full screen
                fullscreenButton: true,
                fullscreenClass: 'fa fa-expand | fa fa-compress',
                fullscreenDiff: 3,
                onFullscreen: function (e) {
                },
                // order
                buttonOrder: '%refresh% %custom% %edit% %toggle% %fullscreen% %delete%',
                opacity: 1.0,
                dragHandle: '> header',
                placeholderClass: 'jarviswidget-placeholder',
                indicator: true,
                indicatorTime: 600,
                ajax: true,
                timestampPlaceholder: '.jarviswidget-timestamp',
                timestampFormat: 'Last update: %m%/%d%/%y% %h%:%i%:%s%',
                refreshButton: true,
                refreshButtonClass: 'fa fa-refresh',
                labelError: 'Sorry but there was a error:',
                labelUpdated: 'Last Update:',
                labelRefresh: 'Refresh',
                labelDelete: 'Delete widget:',
                afterLoad: function () {
                },
                rtl: false, // best not to toggle this!
                onChange: function () {
                },
                onSave: function () {
                },
                ajaxnav: $.navAsAjax // declears how the localstorage should be saved
            });
        }

        return {
            layout: function() {
                $timeout(layout, 1000);
            }
        };
    });
})(window.yourApp);
```

Your controller should then look like this:

```
function($scope, $http, presenter) {
    ...
    $http("api/data").success(function(data) {
        $scope.dataSeries= data;
        presenter.layout();
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Darneas. Thank you for your reply. Could you elaborate your answer with a little bit of code? I'm very grateful!

Comment: It's much clearer, but I still can't get it to work. Do you by chance have a jsfiddle running with an example?

Comment: Unfortunately, these widgets are not open-source so I cannot build a fiddle. The code you need is given in the edited answer. When you post your relevant parts (complete controller function), I can have a look at it.