# how to get the created event of element which generated by angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used ng-repeat to generate some html elements . like this:

`<textarea ng-repeat="t in tips">{{t.content}}</textarea>`

then i want to resize all of textarea's hight according to t.content. 
and textarea width is fixed ,what should i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a function when ng-repeat has finished](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize might help.

Comment: @Karthikeyan there is a jQuery plugin for this . http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/

Answer (score 1):

You should write a directive for this. Maybe similar to this basic one:

```
app.directive('adjustHeight', function($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            $timeout(function() {
                element[0].style.height = element[0].scrollHeight + 'px';
            });
        }
    };
});
```

and use it like this:

```
<textarea ng-repeat="t in tips" adjust-height>{{t.content}}</textarea>
```

It's very naive of course, but you can get the idea. Of course you can build something more sophisticated on top of it if you need for example dynamic resize.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/UDCjfQpXjhA4ISioq28W?p=preview