# Access compiled ng-repeat children elements in link function of a custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, frontend

I want to get ng-repeat children elements of a parent container in my custom directive's link function. I expect *element* parameter passed in *link* function should do the job. Something like this

```
element.children() // gets all children elements
```

instead I've got text node 
    `<!-- ngRepeat: course in courses -->`

This is my directive element:

```
<course-list courses="courses"></course-list>
```

and here is the directive implementation

```
angular.module('pgCoursesList', [])
.directive('coursesList', [
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E', 
            scope: {
                courses: '=',
                buttonText: '@'
            },
            template: '<div class="courseslist-container">' +
                    '<div ng-repeat="course in courses" class="media">' +
                        '<div class="media-left"><a class="img-thumb-64 blank-thumb-img" href="#">64x64</a></div>' +
                        '<div class="media-body clearfix">' +
                            '<h4 class="media-heading pull-left">{{course.name}}</h4>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="media-left"><button btn-style="btn-success"></button></div>' +
                        '<hr />' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>',
            replace: true,
            link: function(scope, elem) {
                // elem.children()   
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: could you share your code in fiddle ?

Answer (score 1):

It is some sort of hack but you can do it using `ng-init`.
We can track last element is rendered on DOM or not by checking `$last` inside `ng-repeat`. Only you need to add `ng-init="$last && domRendered()"` inside ng-repeat div.

**Code changes**

```
template: '<div class="courseslist-container">' +
 '<div ng-repeat="course in courses" class="media">' +
 '<div class="media-left"><a class="img-thumb-64 blank-thumb-img" href="#" ng-init="$last && domRendered()">64x64</a></div>' +
  '<div class="media-body clearfix">' +
   '<h4 class="media-heading pull-left">{{course.name}}</h4>' +
  '</div>' +
  '<div class="media-left"><button btn-style="btn-success"></button></div>' +
  '<hr />' +
 '</div>' +
'</div>',
link: function(scope, element){
  scope.domRendered = function(){
     element.children(); //you can get element children here
  };
 }
```

Or more better way you can try [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished) link. for that you need to add one more directive.

Hope this could help you.
Thanks.

Comment: @Stanislav Zaichenko does this helped you?