# execute function on ng repeat finish

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a ng-repeat of divs, and when I try to access these divs on load, they don't exist yet. How do I execute a function when ng-repeat finishes? I tried directives, but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Check for `$last` property inside `ng-repeat` loop. When it's set, you can execute the function

Comment: Possiblly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished

Comment: @squiroid I tried that method, it didn't work. Mohamedrias, how would I do that? could you give me an example?

Comment: Is the function available in correct scope? you can run easily when $last is true

Comment: Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/buQmxsek

Comment: Just a sample : http://jsbin.com/pobiyaqoca/1/edit?html,js,output @ZygimantasMagelinskas

Comment: HTML - http://pastebin.com/MEKkCRj9

Comment: JS - http://pastebin.com/gEBiXp46

Comment: Doesn't call alert("ria")

Comment: Maybe you could use watch$ functionality with conditionals?

Comment: How would I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

If the possible duplicate doesn't fulfil your needs here's a way to do it - [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E7vYgBPwd1sBeObEl2vd?p=preview).

JS

```
app = angular.module("app", []);

app.directive("test", [ function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<div ng-repeat='item in ts.items track by $index' ng-init='ts.blah($index, $last)'>{{$index}}</div>",
        scope: {},
        controllerAs: "ts",
        bindToController: true,
        controller:function() {
          var ts = this;
          ts.items = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
          ts.blah = function(index, last) {
            console.log(index, last);
            if (last) {
              // Do your stuff
            }
          }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <test></test>
  </body>

</html>
```

The output from the console is:

> 0 false 
>  1 false 
>   2 false 
>   3 false 
>   4 true

so you should (in theory) be able to rely on the last repeat element being created last.