# Scroll AngularJS ngRepeat with Ajax loading data

Tags: angularjs, scroll, angularjs-ng-repeat

First of all a plunk: http://embed.plnkr.co/C866y3LHCE7QfBGuFQPQ/preview

So here I'm getting a set of posts via Ajax and displaying them using ngRepeat. Then (when the posts are done rendering) I want to scroll the page to a specific post (let's say post №18). Seems simple, but I can't get it working.

The problem seems to be that angular can't find that post after it receives the data from Ajax, so the `position()` and `scrollTop()` functions are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait until after the view has been updated with your new model, use `$timeout` waiting 0 milliseconds to scroll immediately after the DOM is ready

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/coD7VvXSLrXGphP7LN5H?p=preview)

```
  $scope.getPosts = function() {
    $http.get(data_url).success(function(data){
      $scope.posts = data;
      $timeout(function() {
        var post = $('#pid_18');
        console.log('pid_18', post);
        $('body').scrollTop(post[0].offsetTop);
      }, 0);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the render is not finish then if you have 2 element it's could be work but not with 1000.

So the best way is to know when the rendering is finish, a related post :

[Calling a function when ng-repeat has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished)