# Unable to get Masonry to work at all

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, masonry

I've been trying to make Masonry (also tried Salvattore but none of them will work) to work for a good few hours now, I've followed multiple tutorials and examples but it just won't happen for some reason. I'm using Bootstrap's grid system and angular to create the number of columns.

**EDIT:** I created a simple fiddle which actually seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/j57vnaa2/1/

Question is, why doesn't my original code work?

I've included Masonry through the CDN, I've checked the console that the script has loaded and indeed it has. Also did it via bower and NPM to test if it worked with those but it yielded the same result.

I've set the class `js-masonry` to my container, which is a `row` with grid columns looped out via `ng-repeat`. Then I have set the `data-masonry-options='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item" }'` as well as applied the class `grid-item` to my columns. But it just doesn't want to work, it's not doing ANYTHING.

I don't know what else that could be wrong, I've searched and searched the web but come up with no solution.

Is there something obviously wrong here?

```
<div class="row padding">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="grid js-masonry row" data-masonry-options='{ "itemSelector": ".grid-item"}'>
      <h1 class="text-center">Similar movies</h1>
      <div ng-repeat="movie in similarMovies"
           class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 grid-item cut-off">
        <a href="#/movies/{{movie.id}}">
          <figure>
            <img ng-src="{{getSrc(movie.poster_path)}}" alt="{{movie.title}}"
                 class="image enlarge">
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean to say it is not working with `ng-repeat` ? could you reproduce issue here https://jsfiddle.net/j57vnaa2/2/ ?

Comment: @PankajParkar I'm on it.

Comment: @PankajParkar Unable to reproduce exactly the way it is due to the fact that I'm calling an API to set $scope.similarMovies, could it be that the masonry script runs before the async task is done or something like that? Because when I made an example of your fiddle with images it works: https://jsfiddle.net/j57vnaa2/3/ But in my original code nothing happens, no animations or nothing.

Comment: are you setting up your plugin by calling its any of **Masonry** API method? may be that is getting run before your element gets render..could you try to call it after `ng-repeat` rendering gets finished

Comment: @PankajParkar No, I'm just initializing it in the HTML since I'm using angular. Don't want to have to create a directive for it if possible.

Comment: @PankajParkar How would I call it after the ng-repeat?

Comment: could you try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15208347/2435473 this will tell when `ng-repeat` finished is rendering

Comment: How are you opening your working file in the browser? (via webserver or directly from file)

Comment: @PankajParkar I've almost got it working with an angular plugin which uses a directive and like a billion dependencies. But my container becomes 2.000.000px high for some odd reason..

Comment: @Loqman I let grunt serve my project.