# A directive to detect $last is not working with ng-if in angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I am working on a news feed page with angular.js and jquery.

I am using a directive to detect the last feed to show. when it return `scope.$last ==true`, I call a function to do some Jquery animation.

Then, I added a ng-model `showYear` to filer elements by date, and added `ng-if` to filter elements.

My problem is, when the last element is filtered by `ng-if` and not rendered,
the directive can not detect `scope.$last` and run `feedPosition()`.

I've tried to do it like the url below but it face the same problem: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished).

Kindly please Help.

here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="feedList">
    <div ng-repeat="feed in feeds | orderBy: '-date'" ng-if="show(feed.date)" feed-list-repeat-directive>
        //some content here
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
var feeds = [{
    "type" : "publications",
    "source" :"AAA",
    "date" : new Date(2014, 4, 10),
    "title" : "title 2014",
    "thrumb" : "thrumb1.jpg"
},{
    "type" : "tvc",
    "source" : "BBB",
    "date" : new Date(2015, 4, 10),
    "title" : "title 2015",
    "thrumb" : "thrumb2.jpg"
}];

var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('anCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.showYear = 2015;
     $scope.feeds = feeds;
    $scope.show = function(yr){
        return Number(yr.getFullYear())==$scope.showYear;
    };
})
.directive('feedListRepeatDirective', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    if (scope.$last){
        feedPosition(true);
    };
  };
});


function feedPosition(){
    for(a=0; a<$('#feedList > div').length; a++){       
        // do something to animate elements position
    };
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, `$last` applies to the array `feeds`, ordered by `date`. The `ng-if` is controlling whether each item is rendered or not, but it is not actually filtering the list.

In order to filter the list in such a way that `$last` will behave as required, remove the `ng-if` and use Angular's [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). `filter` selects a subset of items from the `feeds` array, according to the `show` function, and returns them as a new array. The new array contains only those elements that the `show` function returns `true` for.

```
<div ng-repeat="feed in feeds | filter: show | orderBy: '-date'" feed-list-repeat-directive>
    //some content here
</div>
```

Note that the `show` function will have to be modified slightly to take a full feed as input rather than a date:

```
$scope.show = function(feed){
    return Number(feed.yr.getFullYear())==$scope.showYear;
};
```

Comment: Hi,  someone suggested me to use ng-show instead of ng-if. I think that  looks alike your solution.  However, I don't want all feeds of all years rendered in the dom and just hiding unseleted items.   

btw, I've given up ng-if. Instead, I setup a model for selecting year, each time user change the selected year I made a new $http call.

Comment: Hi, `ng-show` isn't like my solution. `ng-show` renders the items to the DOM but hides them by applying `.ng-hide` class. The solution in my answer uses `filter` to select a subset of items from the array and return them as a new array. So the excluded items are not rendered. Answer updated to clarify this. However your solution sounds like it will also work, although with the overhead of additional `$http` calls.

Comment: Ic, thanks very much,  
I found the $http way suits my job more as I don't need the data of all years at the same time. but I think this is still a useful showcase.

Will try it when available, thanks very much.  :)