# get length of angular js ng-repeat li listing items with jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, hover, angularjs-ng-repeat, domready

I am making `ul-li` list using angular `ng-repeat`. But on `DOMReady` i want total length of that list that has been generated and i want to run an event on that `li` on "hover" or "click". 
But the length iam getting is 0 and no event is firing. What can be the best method to get that?
Thanks in advance!

```
 <ul class="megamenuUL">
        <li ng-class="{'active':$index==0}" data-ng-repeat="cg in GroupList">
</li>
    </ul>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
          console.log($("ul.megamenuUL > li").length);
    });
    </script >
```

events that i need to fire on hover of that `li`

```
 $("#divOffers ul.megamenuUL > li > a").hover(function () {

                   $("#divOffers .megamenuUL > li").removeClass('active');
                   $(this).parent().find("#divOffers ul.megasubmenu li").removeClass('active');
                   $(this).parent().find("#divOffers ul.megasubmenu li:eq(0)").addClass('active');
                   $(this).parent().addClass('active');
               });
```

U see , i cant use angular for this

Comment: post the code you already have so we can take a look at it

Comment: I´d recommend to use the `ng-mouseover` and `ng-click` attributes in your templates <li>...</li>

Comment: You don't have to use jquery just for events binding,same thing is possible with angular itself ,refer @schlangguru's comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery loads before angular, so you will need a delay to obtain the length with jQuery, i.e `setInterval` ..

Or you can do this with angular itself with the help of the answer of the following question :

[Calling a function when ng-repeat has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished)

if you need to execute some code after the repeat finishes and obtain the length from the GroupList object itself using `length` property.

You can also use angular `ng-mouseover` and `ng-mouseleave` events to bind hover to functions from controller

```
<li ng-class="{'active':$index==0}" data-ng-repeat="cg in GroupList" ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
```

Also angular has jqLite which is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows Angular to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way. So you can benefit from a similar jQuery behavior within you event handling.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <li ng-class="{'active':$index==0}" data-ng-repeat="cg in GroupList"  on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">

</li>    
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function (ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
   //do stuff, execute functions -- whatever...
    });
```

Thanks !!