# Complete rendering page first before executing a function in angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, onload

I have this code in javascript

```
$scope.sample = function(){
    console.log(document.getElementById('foo'+modelId));
}
```

which returns false due to the HTML not yet complete rendering the page. See below:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" >
<input ng-model='foo'{{item.modelId}}
</li>
```

I want to avoid using timeout, is there a way to assure the HTML is completely rendered before executing the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way is to listen to scope.$last event and than run any code you need.

Here is an example:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('repeatFinished', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last) { // Here we can see that all ng-repeat items rendered
            scope.$eval(attrs.repeatFinished);
        }
    }
});
```

And than on your html you simple add:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items"  repeat-finished="sample()">
//....
</li>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I've searched similar problems to mine and they've also suggested listening to the last item. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished this thread provides a better understanding.