# Digest loop after modifying passed scope from inside a filter module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I needed a solution to recognize if the `$last` event occurred after an ng-repeat dynamic filtering \ adding of items because angular doesn't identify changes to the iterated object- unless the object gets more properties.
I tried to use **[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26091943/3612903)**, but I also needed to pass local scope to the filter module I created, something like this :

`<div ng-repeat="item in (list.content | ngrepeatEndEventFilter: this)" >`, and it was in that moment that the app entered a `$disgest loop`. I know I shouldn't access or especially edit the scope through filter modules, but I couldn't get the filter module to emit events without doing so (***[as suggested before at the above link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26091943/3612903)***) - I'm getting an error stating that **`me.$emit is not a function`**.

My questions are:

***1.*** Is there a more elegant and whole solution to the `ng-repeat` `$last` event detection issue than the one **[suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26091943/3612903)**?

***2.*** How come that calling `var me = this; me.$emit('eventName')` from inside a filter module returns an error?

Thanks.