# Firing an event when ng-repeat has finished it's work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to update the style for a particular element after ng-repeat has finished changing the dom. Here is my challenge. The directive I have written to fire ng-repeat work's just fine when I am adding items to the model, it doesn't get called though when I remove an object from the item.

I have added a function that randomly pushes and pops data from the list. You will see that the pop doesn't trigger the ng-repeat directive call. Anyway to work around that?

```
var module = angular.module('testApp', [])
.directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        if (scope.$last === true) {
            scope.$evalAsync(attr.onFinishRender);
        }
    }
}
});
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/W8nhv/109/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<p ng-repeat="t in ta" on-finish-render="test()"
    ng-init="myFunction($last, t)">{{t}}</p>
```

```
$scope.myFunction = function(isLast, item){
    if(isLast)
        console.log(item)
}
```

[`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) is an attribute that runs when the element is created.
[`$last`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) is a boolean value that is `true` if the current element is the last element in an `ng-repeat`.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8nhv/113/)

Comment: I did a quick check, `ng-init` is not getting fired when I remove an element. That is essentially the event I need to update the dom height.

Comment: Hm, that may be because the existing elements aren't being updated. I'm not quite sure how to fix that.

Comment: Yep. the directive works perfectly fine as long as I am adding things to the array. It's the removal that I need help with

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the $watch?

```
$scope.$watch('ta', function (newVal, oldValue) {
    if(oldValue.length > 0)
    {
        var i = 0; // do something
    }
}, true);
```

This way you can control when you either push or pop items to the array.

http://jsfiddle.net/W8nhv/114/

Comment: `if(oldValue.length !== newValue.length)`, then this should work.

Comment: I actually need the dom element's height after the ng-repeat has finished it's operation. This will be triggered before the dom operation is over.

Comment: You want the height of the entire list after the list item has been removed?

Comment: @Gen4ik yep, the parent element's height. Also I have this ng-repeat in another ng-repeat. Therefore, I am not sure of the object's name that I could watch individual ones for change. Essentially looking for not a very dirty way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you add an *element* to the *array*. Therefore, it surely triggers its own `link()` function when being rendered. Just keep in mind that you create a `onFinishRender` *directive* for each *element* in your *array* with its own *scope*.

What do you want to do after the *array* length has changed? Maybe a *directive* is not the right attempt.

Comment: Right you are. I had to use a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and effective way

```
<li ng-repeat="data in dataList" ng-init="$last && $parent.myOnFinishHandler();" ></li>
```

**$parent** pointing to the scope where datalist is stored

```js
angular.module("abc", []).controller('mc', function($scope) {
  $scope.dataList = ["abc", "123", "xyz", "orange", "apple"];
  $scope.myHandler = function() {
    console.log("render finish ");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="abc">
  <ul ng-controller="mc">
    <li ng-repeat="data in dataList" ng-init="$last && $parent.myHandler();"> {{data}} </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution hunting around in [one of the other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26091943/393459).

Turns out there is no good way to achieve this functionality. I have written a filter which essentially does what I want it to do. The basics are:

```
app.filter('ngRepeatFinish', function($timeout){
    return function(data, scope){
        //var scope = this;
        var flagProperty = '__finishedRendering__';
        if(!data[flagProperty]){
            Object.defineProperty(
                data, 
                flagProperty, 
                {enumerable:false, configurable:true, writable: false, value:{}});
            $timeout(function(){
                    delete data[flagProperty];                        
                    scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
                },0,false);                
        }
        return data;
    };
})
```

The above filter broadcasts for every element that is created and I get to run my watch based on the listening event in the controller.

```
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function() {
    //Work thy magic
})
```

To call this directive I have to pass the scope from the HTML and I do that via, this in front of the ngRepeatFinish.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in (items | ngRepeatFinish:this)"></div>
```