# call a function when all ng-repeats are rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a code which makes an ajax call and gets a json object from which the ng-repeat's are rendered. Once this all is rendered I want to call a function which binds some events on rendered element.

```
<div ng-repeat="list in arr | filter: {DegreeName: 'xyz'}">
    <div class="saveprogram">save program</div>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="list in arr | filter: {DegreeName: 'abc'}">
    <div class="saveprogram">save program</div>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="list in arr | filter: {DegreeName: 'test'}">
    <div class="saveprogram">save program</div>
</div>
```

Once all the above ng-repeat are rendered, I want to attach some events on it. I tried

```
$window.onload = function(){
    //someevent
    $(".saveprogram")
}
```

This works but it has some issues in IE.
Can someone help me with some directive which runs once all the ng-repeat are rendered

> Note: I have gone through many posts and tried but that didn't help. I would have used ng-click but this is an existing code and very complex. It has lot of things in it. So I don't want to rewrite everyhing again. And calling function every time on ng-click I didnt find it good. I just want to run the function once, which does all bindings

Comment: That answer solves your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished

Comment: I already saw this but this is for single ng-repeat I think

Comment: ok, if it works for one ng-repeat it works for every. You just should call a method that will count how many times ng repeat finished and when it be 3, you make something...

Comment: isn't there something better than this. Because its like hardcording, counting and all those

Comment: it is not hard and I already implemented what I sad for you, it is just copy and paste

Comment: is that useful to you? (I edited the answer)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do after? Why aren't you binding events using angular in the first place? This all sounds like an XY problem

Comment: Strongly suggest you read: [Thinking in angular if I have a jQuery background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: @charlietfl This is very big code which was written already, so I dont want to change it. I just want to bind the event by runing that function..or else I would have directly used ng-click

Comment: Good luck. This is totally the wrong approach to building angular apps and will likely give you unexpected problems

Comment: @charlietfl I know but its client's requirement ;) This is the only jquery piece in my code everything else is just modifying the object to get the view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Directive**

You can just insert that code before your controller and it will work

```
var module = angular.module('testApp', [])
    .directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit(attr.onFinishRender);
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Notice that I didn't use `.ready()` but rather wrapped it in a `$timeout`. `$timeout` makes sure it's executed when the ng-repeated elements have REALLY finished rendering (because the `$timeout` will execute at the end of the current digest cycle -- **and it will also call `$apply` internally, unlike `setTimeout`**). So after the `ng-repeat` has finished, we use `$emit` to emit an event to outer scopes (sibling and parent scopes).

And then in your controller, you can catch it with `$on`:

```
$scope.counter = 0;
$scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
    $scope.counter++;
    if($scope.counter == 3){
        //CallYourMethodHere()
        $scope.counter = 0;
    } 
});
```

With html that looks something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">
    <div>{{item.name}}}<div>
</div>
```

if **directives** are unclear for you, take a look on this docs:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Reference:
Answere based on [Calling a function when ng-repeat has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished#answer-15208347) Since the user already saw this answre but still with problems. (I just added the counter inside the controller).

Comment: Thanks for you help. I am up voting your answer but looking for a better answer. If I don't get any other answers, I will accept yours

Comment: First part is a direct copy of another answer. You should give attribution when you plagiarize like that

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: by providing link and explanation where it came from. Directly copying answers is very much frowned upon

Comment: I will do that and explain what I've changed. Thank's for the information! XD

Answer (score 1):

You should create a directive and include the directive into Your ng-repeat element.

```
<div ng-repeat="list in arr | filter: {DegreeName: 'test'}">
    <div class="saveprogram" directive-to-Do-something>save program</div>
</div>
```

Then when the class element *saveprogram* is created and loaded the directive will do the job. That's the purpose of the directives: attach new behavior to a specific element, that I understood is what You want.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping with jQuery style event registrations, you could use...

```
$window.onload = function(){
    $('document').on('click', '.saveprogram', function(){
         // handle the click event here
         // this will be the clicked element
    })
}
```

Substituting the event you would like to handle.

You'll only need to do this once and you won't have to wait until the `ng-repeat finishes rendering

Comment: To use jquery outside angular directives isn't a good practice. Take a look on this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background?rq=1

Comment: Agreed, but wanted to give OP an alternative to the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

The proper angular approach is to use built in event directives like `ng-click`.

Whatever you do in that event handler in controller would then update scope model and server if needed

```
<div ng-repeat="list in arr | filter: {DegreeName: 'abc'}">
    <div class="saveprogram" ng-click="saveProgram(list)">save program</div>
</div>
```

if you need to use a plugin on those elements then create a custom directive where each element is exposed as jQuery object when jQuery is included in page before angular

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what's your purpose to do this, but for sure you don't need to create a *directive* for this. You could create a function and call it in every `$last` element of `ngRepeat`, then increment a variable and when it becomes 3, you can do what you want, this way:

```
ng-init="$last && increment()"
```

Here's a demonstration:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.items = [];
      for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
        $scope.items.push('Item ' + i);
      }

      var inc = 0;
      $scope.increment = function() {
        inc++;
        if (inc == 3) {
          // do something
          console.log(inc);
        }
      }
    });

})();
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="$last && increment()">
    <div class="saveprogram">save program</div>
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="$last && increment()">
    <div class="saveprogram">save program</div>
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="$last && increment()">
    <div class="saveprogram">save program</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So you are proposing to put DOM code in controller? That is certainly a bad practice

Comment: OP is asking how to use DOM code to add event listeners .... *"I want to attach some events on it"*. The whole question seems to be a complete XY problem

Comment: @charlietfl, yes.. I saw it now.