# How to modify the transcluded content of a custom directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, single-page-application, angularjs-ng-transclude

Im using `angular 1.x` and I have created a custom directive called slider as following code.

I'm trying to `transclude` the content of slider directive in order to modify it inside the transclude function. But the problem is clone is not giving a collection of .slide elements. Instead it gives a comment which relates to `ng-repeat`. I cannot get the compiled output of `ng-repeat` which should be a collection of `.slide divs.` I want to know how to access the result of `ng-repeat` inside `transclude` function so that I can successfully call `scope.showCurrent.` Now what happens is, `$('.slide')` call inside `scope.showCurrent()` doesnt catch any `.slide` divs because at the time of call there are no `.slide` elements. But if `ng-repeat` provided its compiled html inside transclude function, `$('.slide')` will catch divs.

```
app.directive('slider', function ($compile) {
     return {
          restrict: 'EA',
          priority: 1200,
          scope: true,
          controller: function ($scope) {
               $scope.slider = { currentIndex: 0 };
          },
          transclude:'element',
          link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {

               scope.showCurrent = function (currentIndex) {
                    console.log('x')
                    $('.slide').hide();
                    $('.slide').eq(currentIndex).show();
               }

               scope.$watch('slider.currentIndex', function (val) {
                    console.log('tst');
                    scope.showCurrent(val);
               });

               transclude(scope, function (clone) {
                    el.after(clone);
                    scope.showCurrent(scope.slider.currentIndex);
               })
          },
     }
});
```

Following is the html usage of this directive.

```
<slider>
  <div ng-repeat="slide in slides" class="slide">
     <div>Image {{img}}</div>
     <img ng-src="img"/>
   </div>
</slider>
```

Here is my plunk
https://plnkr.co/edit/m7YJBNuDjeLPaKkUYK5S?p=preview

Comment: why do you want to use transclusion here? your directive doesn't create isolate scope, and transclusion is usually used to bind inner elements to outer scope

Comment: I explained in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39947320/2545680) why you don't get `slides`. If you clearly explain what is your original intent, I may be able to provide a solution

Comment: Thanks Maximus and you're right. What I wanted was to modify the content of the clone inside transclude function. The problem was I think its because ngRepeat itself another transcluded directive which is not rendered while in link function of slider directive I created. The workaround I found was to add another directive on ngRepeat which signals the rendering complete event which emitted up with scope.$emit and catch that in the slider directive as indicated by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished

Comment: Is there any better way to modify the transcluded clone if it contains another transcluded directive (which is rendered as a comment)?

Comment: tell me why do you need transclusion?

Comment: Im trying to add the content of this directive into a template which can be done by a templateUrl, but I needed to access the content of the directive and modify it before attaching it to a templateUrl html.

Comment: do you use `ng-transclude` directive in the template?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125295/discussion-between-xpd-and-maximus).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get `.slide divs` because at the time your code inside `transclude` is being executed:

```
el.after(clone);
scope.showCurrent(scope.slider.currentIndex);
```

the linking functions of the inner content, particularly `ng-repeat`'s linking function, has not been executed yet. It's inside this linking function a watcher is added for the `slides`.

Even if you wait until the linking functions get executed, as in here:

```
transclude(scope, function (clone) {
    el.after(clone);
    scope.showCurrent(scope.slider.currentIndex);
})
// here the linking functions of the `clone` have already been executed
```

`.slide divs` are still not available until the first digest loop runs.

**After your update**

You definitely don't need this part here

```
transclude(scope, function (clone) { 
    el.after(clone); 
    scope.showCurrent(scope.slider.currentIndex); 
})
```

because it will be different `clone` that the one processed by `ng-transclude`
and `ng-transclude` will take care of compiling and linking the content. You have to wait until digest loops runs and ng-repeat renders the `div .slider` elements. For that, use `$timeout`:

```
$timeout(function() {
    scope.showCurrent(scope.slider.currentIndex);
});
```