# AngularJS - Callback For When a New Filter Has Been Applied to Ng-Repeat?

Tags: angularjs, callback, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an `ng-repeat` element that looks something like:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages | limitTo: customVariable">
```

where `customVariable` is constantly changed in my controller.  Every time `customVariable` is changed, the parent / container element to the `ng-repeat` elements has its height adjusted since a different number of `messages` will pass the filter.

I need to get the before and after height of the parent div when this happens.  I can get the before height with a simple call to the element `height()` method.  For me to be able to get the after height, I need a callback that I can pass a function into after the DOM updates with changes from the `limitTo` filter.

How do I register such a callback?  If the underlying array (in this case `messages`) for the `ng-repeat` changes, I can use the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207788/calling-a-function-when-ng-repeat-has-finished).  But in this case, the underlying array stays the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the filtered result by using `as`:

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages | limitTo: customVariable as filteredMessages">
```

You can then add a watcher to this array from a controller or inside a directive and react to changes:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return $scope.filteredMessages;
}, function() {
  // Do something
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/kQeLVJ2zLZCDeokyLqlW?p=preview