# CSS Transition Happening Before Animation Set

Tags: javascript, css, html, transition

I have an element that I've changed the style of (Either through changing the class or modifying the style).

I then wish to add a transition so that later changes will be animated.

For some reason, when I set the style before the transition, the style is still animated. This is happening in the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.

Example:
http://codepen.io/DavidBradbury/pen/IxfmF

JS Snippet [Library is jQuery but it shouldn't matter]:

```
$(function() {
  $("#toggle").on({
    click: function(e) {
      // ## Change the class / style
      // At this point, it shouldn't know that
      // a transition will be added
      $("#badidname").toggleClass('newclass');

      // Then add the transition
      $("#badidname").css({
        "transition": "all 600ms"
      });

      // For some reason, it animates 
      // the class being added
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the transition in a timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() { $("#badidname").css({ "transition": "all 600ms" }); }, 0);
```

Here's a great explanation over the oddness of `setTimeout(..., 0);` [setTimeout with zero delay used often in web pages, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574940/settimeout-with-zero-delay-used-often-in-web-pages-why)

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. It seems a bit hacky, but I can understand why it would be done that way.